# Possible to use string formatting to split a string value?

Tags: python, string, split, format

EDIT: 
I'm stuck with python 2.7.5 ...

ANOTHER EDIT: 
Clarifying the need for the changes to be in the template, not the code handling the dictionary.

I'm using a string formatter for building paths from templates.

I know I can do this:

```
currentUser = {'first': "Monty", 'last': "Python"}
template = '/usr/{user[last]}/{user[first]}' # will come from a config file
template.format(user=currentUser)
# Result: '/usr/Python/Monty'
```

but in the case of

```
currentUser = {'first': "Raymond", 'last': "Luxury-Yacht"}
```

Is there a way to split, say, by `-` and use an index?

```
# something like:
template = '/usr/{user[last].split(-)[0]/{user[first]}' # will come from a config file
template.format(user=currentUser)
# Result: '/usr/Luxury/Raymond'
```

The decision to choose:

- which key to split
- by what character
- which index to use from split

**MUST come from the template string**; if the current mini-language can't achieve this, I will have to write a custom formatter.

DISCLAIMER: The example is a bit contrived, and not practical, I know.  I'm actually dealing with a database where two key bits of information are stored in a single field, joined by underscores -_-.  I understand that I could do post-processing on the data after extracting it from the database, but due to conventions for this field differing per-project, I can't even assume that a split operation is valid (some values on some projects won't have the underscore issue).  Rather than code a solution around each convention, I'm hoping to be able to provide users with a template "language" so each project can themselves determine how to extract that data, adapt to whatever naming convention they choose, and configure their templates accordingly.

TL/DR: I'm not looking for a solution to fixing my incoming data -- I'm exploring the possibility of splitting strings **using Python's string format mini-language**.

Comment: I am comfortable writing a custom string.Formatter that introduces this behavior into the spec, but do not want to re-invent the wheel if that functionality already exists natively.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dictionary comprehension:

```
currentUser = {'first': "Raymond", 'last': "Luxury-Yacht"}
template = '/usr/{user[last]}/{user[first]}'
template.format(user={a:b.split('-')[0] if '-' in b else b for a, b in currentUser.items()})
```

Output:

```
'/usr/Luxury/Raymond'
```

This will also work for your first example:

```
currentUser = {'first': "Monty", 'last': "Python"}
template = '/usr/{user[last]}/{user[first]}'
template.format(user={a:b.split('-')[0] if '-' in b else b for a, b in currentUser.items()})
```

Output:

```
'/usr/Python/Monty'
```

As a side note, it is more Pythonic to use unpacking (`**`) in your formatting to remove the `__getitem__` call in the string itself:

```
currentUser = {'first': "Raymond", 'last': "Luxury-Yacht"}
template = '/usr/{last}/{first}'.format(**{a:b.split('-')[0] if '-' in b else b for a, b in currentUser.items()})
```

Comment: The limitation I have is that I can't split the string with code, I *have* to rely on the template string to tell python how to extract the item.

Comment: `{key: val.split("-")[0] if key == "last" else val for key, val in currentUser.items()}` to only split last names.

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to Python 3.6, you can use [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/):

```
users = [{'first': "Raymond", 'last': "Luxury-Yacht"}, 
         {'first': "Monty", 'last': "Python"}]

sep = '-'
for user in users:
    path = f"/usr/{user['last'].split(sep)[0]}/{user['first'].split(sep)[0]}"
    print(path)
```

---

```
/usr/Luxury/Raymond
/usr/Python/Monty
```

---

However, if you want to stick to your dict style formatting in Python 2, you can use the current template with a small wrapper class that does the clean up of the dictionary values:

```
class Wrapper(object):
    __slots__ = ('sep', 'dct')

    def __init__(self, dct, sep='-'):
        self.sep = sep
        self.dct = dct

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.dct[key].split(self.sep)[0]

template = '/usr/{user[last]}/{user[first]}'
for usr in map(Wrapper, users):
    path = template.format(user=usr)
    print(path)
```

---

```
/usr/Luxury/Raymond
/usr/Python/Monty
```

---

Comment: Dang! That looks like exactly what I want, but unfortunetaly, I'm stuck with Python2

Comment: @RyandeKleer Python2 is being phased out shortly, so it may make sense for you to migrate your codebase to Python3 anyway.

Comment: @Ajax1234
Absolutely, and in preparation for that, we're writing 2/3 compliancy as much as possible, but we don't get to pull that trigger:  until certain software applications (VFX/film industry) make that switch, we're stuck on 2 :(

Comment: @RyandeKleer Ah, I understand.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye
The wrapper *assumes* a separator, the problem is that I can't.  That's why I need the choice to be in the hands of those writing the templates (non-programmers) rather than being in the code.
Perhaps I should clarify my question...

Comment: @RyandeKleer They can pass a custom separator if they want `Wrapper(user, sep='_')`, why not...